# Add icon to Unity panel during/after package installation

Tags: unity, packaging

Intro:  I am currently creating a custom Ubuntu ISO for an appliance I am creating. All work on the development of this ISO is done in a chroot, so there is no graphical environment. What I would like to do is when my client package is installed, have it add an icon/launcher to the Unity panel (on the left) so the end user doesn't have to do this manually. I have looked all over my chroot to find out where the default apps are located and have been unsuccessful. For instance, after installing Ubuntu, the first time I log in there are a set of default icons in the Unity bar (on the left). How do I get my package/application to add one there automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's stored as a `dconf` key:

```
$ gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
['nautilus.desktop', 'chromium-browser.desktop', 'terminator.desktop', 'gedit.desktop',
'libreoffice-startcenter.desktop', 'banshee.desktop', 'ubuntu-software-center.desktop']
```

I'm not sure of a way to do what you want in a policy compliant way short of patching the package providing the default schema. I'm sure you can imagine some hacky approaches in the postinstall.

Comment: Thanks andrew! With your hint and http://askubuntu.com/questions/153597/editing-gsettings-add-icon-to-launcher-by-command that post, I figured it out.